# ReSharper: find derived types constructor usages points

Tags: resharper

I have some base class `ControlBase` and many derived classes which also have derived classes... `ControlBase` and derived classes have parameterless constructor. How can I easily find all derived classes constructor invocation points? ReSharper *find usages* on `ControlBase` constructor shows only usages of this base class constructor but not derived classes constructors.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the structural search feature in Resharper 5.

Go to Resharper/Find/Search with Pattern in the menu. Then enter the following pattern in the textbox on the left:

```
new $type$($args$)
```

The words enclosed by the Dollar signs are placeholders which have to be specified. You can do this by clicking on "Add Placeholder".

In your example you need a Type placeholder (name=type, Type=ControlBase, check "Or derived type") and an Argument placeholder (name=args).

Comment: Thanks, this is better solution that one I used before: VS Regular Expressions. I do not understand why, but when I am searching pattern `new $ControlBase$` it successfully finds `new Derived2()` but not `new Derived2{}` or even `new Derived2(){}` (constructor call with properties initializer). Mystery...